# Rust compiler can't find crate for 'std'

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I recently downloaded and unpacked the Rust Language from [this site](https://www.rust-lang.org/downloads.html) (Linux 64-bit).

I then installed Rust using the given script in the download `install.sh`:

```
root@kali:~# /root/rust-1.9.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/install.sh
install: uninstalling component 'rustc'
install: creating uninstall script at /usr/local/lib/rustlib/uninstall.sh
install: installing component 'rustc'
install: installing component 'rust-std-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
install: installing component 'rust-docs'
install: installing component 'cargo'

    Rust is ready to roll.
```

I am trying to install a crate with cargo, but I keep running into this error:

```
root@kali:~# cargo install racer
    Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
   Compiling winapi v0.2.7
   Compiling bitflags v0.5.0
error: can't find crate for `std` [E0463]
error: aborting due to previous error
Build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: can't find crate for `std` [E0463]
error: aborting due to previous error
error: failed to compile `racer v1.2.10`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/root/target-install`
```

`cargo install cargo-edit` failed with the same result as above, so it's not limited to one particular package.

Even putting a simple program:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

in a file named `hello.rs` and running `rustc hello.rs` does not compile; it gives the same error: `error: can't find crate for 'std' [E0463]`.

The download came with a directory named `rust-std-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`, which I assume is the std crate. How do I instruct rustc to find this directory when trying to locate the std crate?

Comment: Can you compile Rust code other than Racer? For example, try `cargo install cargo-edit`. Although Racer needs the source code of std, the error message sounds like *the compiler* can't find the std *binaries*, so it can't even compiler Racer.

Comment: @delnan: Apparently even "Hello, world!" does not compile, so I would tend to agree that the issue here is `rustc` not knowing where the `std` crate is.

Comment: You could try using [rustup](https://www.rustup.rs/).

Comment: @Chris Morgan thanks for suggesting rustup; I'll look in to it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work for the simplest of compilations.
Assuming you extracted the tar file to, say

```
$HOME/rust-1.10.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Then run

```
arch=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
dl=$HOME/rust-1.10.0-$arch
$dl/rustc/bin/rustc -L $dl/rustc/lib \
    -L $dl/rust-std-$arch/lib/rustlib/$arch/lib \
    hello.rs
```

But I'm sure a better way would be to run rustup as Chris Morgan suggest.

Coupla more points

1. You shouldn't compile code as root.
2. You may have to relogin or run bash -l to get the environment setup by rustup.

(Fellow rust newb here)

Answer (score 3):

The first error-message you encounter (`error: can't find crate for 'std' [E0463]`) could indicate that `rust-std` is not installed.

The command below could help (re-)installing rust-std. Personally,  I missed it after changing target:

```bash
rustup component add rust-std
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question properly because the asker is using the install script, not Rustup. Could you provide some more context for this?

Comment: Was building the leptos sample project for WASM, and I got errors about cargo not finding "std". Specifying the target and installing rust-std for the wasm32 target fixed it: rustup component add rust-std --target wasm32-unknown-unknown . Have to keep installing rust-std every time I cross compile, whether its embedded or wasm or just for another machine

Answer (score 1):

For me (Arch Linux) removing system's Rust fixed the issue.

```
pacman -Rc rust
```

I think there was a conflict among user installed Rust and system installed one.